# Error while saving database file foreignkey constrained failed realese restore point

Tags: python, django, database, foreign-keys

in shell the error I get is:

```
OperationalError: database is locked
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth


class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, help_text="The name of the publisher")
    website = models.URLField(help_text="The website of the publisher")
    email = models.EmailField(help_text="The email of the publisher")

    def str(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, help_text="The title of the book")
    publication_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name="Publication date")
    isbn = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, verbose_name="ISBN number of the book")
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(
        Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contributores = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Contributor', through='BookContributor')

    def str(self):
        return self.title


class Contributor(models.Model):
    first_names = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, help_text="The first names of the contributor")
    last_names = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, help_text="The last names of the contributor")
    email = models.EmailField(help_text="The email of the contributor")

    def str(self):
        return self.first_names


class BookContributor(models.Model):
    class ContributionRole(models.TextChoices):
        AUTHOR = 'AUTHOR', 'Author'
        CO_AUTHOR = 'CO_AUTHOR', 'Co-author'
        EDITOR = 'EDITOR', 'Editor'
        CO_EDITOR = 'CO_EDITOR', 'Co-editor'
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(Contributor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(verbose_name="Contribution role",
                            choices=ContributionRole.choices, max_length=20)


class Review(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(help_text="The review text")
    rating = models.IntegerField(help_text="The rating the reviewer has given")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, help_text="The date and time the review was created")
    date_edited = models.DateTimeField(
        null=True, help_text="The date and time the review was edited")
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        auth.get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text="The book that this review is for")
```

in my db browser for sqlite I get the following message:

[image]

I don't know why I am getting the error, I just eliminated two rows of the reviws_contributor table and when I try to save  I get this error I did this in the dbrowser execute SQL with delete. I use cascade so deleting a record in the parent table may result in related records being deleted in the child table I think that's the issue.

I think there are orphaned records Book records referencing non-existent Publisher, Contributor, or Review records

Comment: The solutions was close DBrowser the everything is working correctly